# PHP: preg_replace_callback changes the order of the result

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have the following code

```
return preg_replace_callback(
    "#\{gallery: '(.+?)'(?: dir: ([0-1]))?\}#i",
    create_function('$i', 'echo $i[1];' ),
    $string);
```

My problem is that if my string looks like this:

```
top
{gallery: 'images/'}
center
{gallery: 'images/characters'}
bottom
```

when it gets rendered it looks like this:

```
images/
images/characters
top center bottom
```

why is the order being changed and bringing the replaced code to the top and everything else to the bottom, even the thing in the middle?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be tagged `regex` rather than `nsregularexpression` ?

Comment: do not `echo` in callback function but `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `return` statement inside the replacement callback:

```
$string = "top {gallery: 'images/'} center {gallery: 'images/characters'} bottom";
$string = preg_replace_callback(
  "#\{gallery: '(.+?)'(?: dir: ([0-1]))?\}#i", 
  create_function('$i', 'return $i[1];'), 
  $string
);
echo $string . PHP_EOL;

// Outputs: top images/ center images/characters bottom
```

Comment: It's 2012. PHP has [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) now

Comment: @ Phil: my server is running on 5.2 :/

Comment: @WaldirBolanos Do you always run six year old software on your servers?

Comment: No Phil, its a clients server (on godaddy.com) Nothing i can do about it,

Comment: Please note that this (create_function()) is depraced with PHP 7.2 and higher. For all version prior to PHP 7.2 it will performs an eval() which has the same security issues as eval(). Also it has bad performance and lot of memory usage.